# how the ble can continuous scan in the background of Android phone based on bluetooth 4.0

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-8.1-oreo

I have a requirement to complete the continuous scanning of bluetooth in the background of Android phone based on bluetooth 4.0. In Android 8.1 and above, when the phone screen is black, the bluetooth information cannot be scanned. I set filter to complete this function. But bluetooth continues to scan in the background for a period of time, the scan is not any information. In addition, I set up a loop operation. After 10 seconds of bluetooth scanning, the scan was stopped for 5 seconds and then continued. After 5 cycles, no information is scanned. Has anyone had this problem?